# cryptic perl expression

Tags: regex, perl, pdl

I find the following statement in a perl (actually PDL) program:

```
/\/([\w]+)$/i;
```

Can someone decode this for me, an apprentice in perl programming?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sure, I'll explain it from the inside out:

`\w` - matches a [single character](http://www.troubleshooters.com/codecorn/littperl/perlreg.htm#UsingSimpleWildcards) that can be used in a word (alphanumeric, plus '_')

`[...]` - matches a single character from [within the brackets](http://www.troubleshooters.com/codecorn/littperl/perlreg.htm#UsingCharacterClasses)

`[\w]` - matches a single character that can be used in a word (kinda redundant here)

`+` - matches the previous character, [repeating as many times](http://www.troubleshooters.com/codecorn/littperl/perlreg.htm#UsingSimpleWildcards) as possible, but must appear at least once.

`[\w]+`  - matches a group of word characters, many times over.  This will find a word.

`(...)` - [grouping](http://www.troubleshooters.com/codecorn/littperl/perlreg.htm#Groups).  remember this set of characters for later.

`([\w]+)` - match a word, and remember it for later

`$` - [end-of-line](http://www.troubleshooters.com/codecorn/littperl/perlreg.htm#op_$).  match something at the end of a line

`([\w]+)$` - match the last word on a line, and remember it for later

`\/` - a single slash character '/'.  it must be escaped by backslash, because slash is special.

`\/([\w]+)$` - match the last word on a line, after a slash '/', and remember the word for later.  This is probably grabbing the directory/file name from a path.

`/.../` - [match](http://www.troubleshooters.com/codecorn/littperl/perlreg.htm#op_/) syntax

`/.../i` - i means [case-insensitive](http://www.troubleshooters.com/codecorn/littperl/perlreg.htm#op_i).

All together now:

`/\/([\w]+)$/i;` - match the last word on a line and remember it for later; the word must come after a slash.  Basically, grab the filename from an absolute path.  The case insensitive part is irrelevant, `\w` will already match both cases.

More details about Perl regex here:  http://www.troubleshooters.com/codecorn/littperl/perlreg.htm

And as JRFerguson pointed out, [YAPE::Regex::Explain](https://metacpan.org/module/YAPE::Regex::Explain) is useful for tokenizing regex, and explaining the pieces.

Comment: Thank you Tim...excellent description and fits perfectly with the context of the code. Looks like I need more regex experience after 40+ years of programming!

Answer (score 5):

You will find the [Yape::Regex::Explain](https://metacpan.org/module/YAPE::Regex::Explain) module worth installing.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use YAPE::Regex::Explain;
#...may need to single quote $ARGV[0] for the shell...
print YAPE::Regex::Explain->new( $ARGV[0] )->explain;
```

Assuming this script is named 'rexplain' do:

```
$ ./rexplain '/\/([\w]+)$/i'
```

...to obtain:

```
The regular expression:

(?-imsx:/\/([\w]+)$/i)

matches as follows:

NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
(?-imsx:                 group, but do not capture (case-sensitive)
                         (with ^ and $ matching normally) (with . not
                         matching \n) (matching whitespace and #
                         normally):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  /                        '/'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \/                       '/'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [\w]+                    any character of: word characters (a-z,
                             A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
                         (with ^ and $ matching normally) (with . not
                         matching \n) (matching whitespace and #
                         normally):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  /                        '/'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \/                       '/'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [\w]+                    any character of: word characters (a-z,
                             A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  /i                       '/i'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
)                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**UPDATE:**

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12359682/1015385 .  As noted there and in the module's documentation:

> There is no support for regular expression syntax added after Perl version 5.6, particularly any
>   constructs added in 5.10.

Answer (score 2):

```
/\/([\w]+)$/i;
```

It is a regex, and if it is a complete statement, it is applied to the `$_` variable, like so:

```
$_ =~ /\/([\w]+)$/i;
```

It looks for a slash `\/`, followed by an alphanumeric string `\w+`, followed by end of line `$`. It also captures `()` the alphanumeric string, which ends up in the variable `$1`. The `/i` on the end makes it case-insensitive, which has no effect in this case.

Answer (score 2):

While it doesn't help "explain" a regex, once you have a test case, Damian's new [`Regexp::Debugger`](http://p3rl.org/Regexp%3a%3aDebugger) is a cool utility to watch what actually occurs during the matching. Install it and then do `rxrx` at the command line to start the debugger, then type in `/\/([\w]+)$/` and `'/r'` (for example), and finally `m` to start the matching. You can then step through the debugger by hitting enter repeatedly. Really cool!

Answer (score 0):

This is comparing `$_` to a slash followed by one or more character (case insensitive) and storing it in `$1`

```
$_ value     then     $1 value 
------------------------------
"/abcdes"     |       "abcdes"
"foo/bar2"    |       "bar2"
"foobar"      |       undef      # no slash so doesn't match
```

Comment: `$1` is undef unless a previous match, in this case its value is unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

The [Online Regex Analyzer](http://www.myezapp.com/apps/dev/regexp/show.ws) deserves a mention. Here's a [link](http://www.myezapp.com/apps/dev/regexp/show.ws?regex=%5C/%28%5B%5Cw%5D+%29%24&env=env_perl) to explain what your regex means, and pasted here for the record.

## Sequence: match all of the followings in order

```
/                                                  (slash)
                                               --+
Repeat                                           | (in GroupNumber:1)
   AnyCharIn[ WordCharacter] one or more times   |
                                               --+
EndOfLine
```