# YAPE::Regex::Explain not working with use 5.014;

Tags: regex, perl

This code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use YAPE::Regex::Explain;
print YAPE::Regex::Explain->new( qr/d+/ )->explain();
```

prints

```
The regular expression:

(?-imsx:d+)

matches as follows:
  
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
(?-imsx:                 group, but do not capture (case-sensitive)
                         (with ^ and $ matching normally) (with . not
                         matching \n) (matching whitespace and #
                         normally):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  d+                       'd' (1 or more times (matching the most
                           amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
)                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

but this code

```
use 5.014;  #added this
use strict;
use warnings;
use YAPE::Regex::Explain;
print YAPE::Regex::Explain->new( qr/d+/ )->explain();
```

prints only:

```
The regular expression:



matches as follows:
  
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What's wrong?

Comment: I don't have an actual answer but have you tried [Regexp::Debugger](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Regexp%3A%3ADebugger)?

Comment: Seems to be the [unicode_strings feature](http://www.perl.com/pub/2011/06/new-features-of-perl-514-unicode-strings.html). You get the same behaviour with `use feature "unicode_strings";`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Feature `unicode_strings` changes which pattern gets created.

```
$ perl -le'no  feature qw( unicode_strings ); print qr/\d+/'
(?^:\d+)

$ perl -le'use feature qw( unicode_strings ); print qr/\d+/'
(?^u:\d+)
```

[YAPE::Regex::Explain](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?YAPE%3a%3aRegex%3a%3aExplain) can't handle many new (and not so new) features due to lack of maintenance. This is documented in the LIMITATIONS section.

I bet it gets the flags using `re::regexp_pattern` (explaining why it displays `(?-imsx:d+)` instead of `(?^:\d+)`), and chokes on the "`u`" flag it doesn't know about.

```
$ perl -le'no  feature qw( unicode_strings ); print +(re::regexp_pattern(qr/\d+/))[1]'


$ perl -le'use feature qw( unicode_strings ); print +(re::regexp_pattern(qr/\d+/))[1]'
u
```